# GET request in retrofit in android is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

**I am trying to learn compose and retrofit and for that I am developing a very easy app, fetching jokes from a public API and showing them in a lazy list. But it is not working and I am not able to see any jokes. I am new to Kotlin and Jetpack compose. Please help me debug this.**

I have a `joke` class

```kotlin
data class Joke(
    val id: Int,.
    val punchline: String,
    val setup: String,
    val type: String
)
```

This is the API I am GETing from:
`https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/jokes/:id` 
This is the response:

```json
{"type":"general","setup":"What did the fish say when it hit the wall?","punchline":"Dam.","id":1}
```

This is the retrofit api service:

```kotlin
const val BASE_URL = "https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/"

interface JokeRepository {

    @GET("jokes/{id}")
    suspend fun getJoke(@Path("id") id: String ) : Joke
    companion object {
        var apiService: JokeRepository? = null
        fun getInstance(): JokeRepository {
            if (apiService == null) {
                apiService = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build().create(JokeRepository::class.java)
            }
            return apiService!!
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Jokes view model:

```kotlin
class JokeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _jokeList = mutableListOf<Joke>()
    var errorMessage by mutableStateOf("")
    val jokeList: List<Joke> get() = _jokeList

    fun getJokeList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val apiService = JokeRepository.getInstance()
            try {
                _jokeList.clear()
//                for(i in 1..100) {
//                    var jokeWithId = apiService.getJoke(i.toString())
//                    _jokeList.add(jokeWithId)
//                    Log.d("DEBUGGG", jokeWithId.setup)
//                }
                var joke = apiService.getJoke("1")
                _jokeList.add(joke)

            }
            catch (e: Exception) {
                errorMessage = e.message.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Main Activity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val jokeViewModel = JokeViewModel()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HasyamTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    JokeView(jvm = jokeViewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Joke Component and view

```kotlin
@Composable
fun JokeView(jvm: JokeViewModel) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit, block = {
        jvm.getJokeList()
    })
    
    Text(text = jvm.errorMessage)
    
    LazyColumn() {
        items(jvm.jokeList) {
            joke -> JokeComponent(joke)
        }
    }

}



@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)

@Composable
fun JokeComponent(joke: Joke) {

    var opened by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)
    ) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable { },
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
                defaultElevation = 5.dp
            ),

            onClick = { opened = !opened}

        ) {
            Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp), text = joke.setup)
        }

        if (opened) {
            Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp), text = joke.punchline)
        }
    }
}
```

**Thank you so much**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are not using stateFlow. The screen is not recomposed so your `LazyColumn` is not recreated with the updated values.

#### ViewModel

```kotlin
class JokeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var errorMessage by mutableStateOf("")
    private val _jokes = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Joke>())
    val jokes = _jokes.asStateFlow()

    fun getJokeList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val apiService = JokeRepository.getInstance()
            try {
                var jokes = apiService.getJoke("1")
                _jokes.update { jokes }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                errorMessage = e.message.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Joke View

```kotlin
@Composable
fun JokeView(jvm: JokeViewModel) {
    
    val jokes by jvm.jokes.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit, block = {
        jvm.getJokeList()
    })

    Text(text = jvm.errorMessage)

    LazyColumn {
        items(jokes) {
                joke -> JokeComponent(joke)
        }
    }
}
```

You should read the following documentation about states : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state

Comment: That worked, Thank you so much! . I will read more about state and state flow.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. add below line in APIService.kt

@GET("sliders")
    fun get_intro_slider(@Query("type") type: String?): Call<IntroSliderResponse?>?

 2. Call below function 

    private fun getIntroSlider() {
        if (AppUtil.isInternetAvailable(this)) {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
                .build()

            val apiService = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)

            APIUtils.getAPIService()?.get_intro_slider(resources.getString(R.string.introduction))
                ?.enqueue(object : Callback<IntroSliderResponse?> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<IntroSliderResponse?>,
                        response: Response<IntroSliderResponse?>
                    ) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                            val status = response.body()!!.getData()
                            if (response.body()!!.getStatus() != null && response.body()!!.getStatus() == 200) {
                                if (response.body()!!.getData() != null && !response.body()!!.getData()?.isEmpty()!!) {
                                    binding.slider.setAdapter(IntroSliderAdapter(this@IntroSlider,response.body()!!.getData(),  binding.slider))
                                } else {
                                    setWatchNow()
                                }
                            } else {
                                setWatchNow()
                            }
                        } else {
                            setWatchNow()
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<IntroSliderResponse?>, t: Throwable) {
                        t.printStackTrace()
                        setWatchNow()
                    }
                })
        } else {
            val dialog_view: View = LayoutInflater.from(this@IntroSlider).inflate(
                AppUtil.setLanguage(this@IntroSlider, R.layout.simple_dialog_text_button),
                null
            )
            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@IntroSlider)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setView(dialog_view)
                .show()
            if (dialog.window != null) dialog.window!!.decorView.background.alpha = 0
            (dialog_view.findViewById<View>(R.id.dialog_text) as TextView).setText(R.string.no_internet_connection)
            dialog_view.findViewById<View>(R.id.dialog_ok).visibility = View.GONE
            (dialog_view.findViewById<View>(R.id.dialog_cancel) as Button).text =
                resources.getString(R.string.ok)
            dialog_view.findViewById<View>(R.id.dialog_cancel)
                .setOnClickListener { view: View? -> dialog.dismiss() }
        }
    }
```